# Объясните, пожалуйста ответы. ЕГЭ.

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте!

Не могу верно найти ответы на 10 вариант http://nsportal.ru/shkola/russkii-yazyk/library/testy-ege
Объясните, пожалуйста, номера B1,B3-B7.

Спасибо.

Comment: Будьте любезны указать, что конкретно Вам непонятно.

Comment: @Noir, я в B1 выписал 7 слов. Не знаю какое правильно. Пожтому и прошу объяснить, что бы понять в чём моя ошибка.

Comment: А вы знаете, какой способ образования слов называют неморфологическим?

Comment: @София, насколько я понимаю, это когда слово меняет часть речи не меняясь по написанию.

Comment: Неморфологический способ образования (без использования морфем) – это переход слова одной части речи в другую часть речи. Так, слово, ПО ФОРМЕ являющееся причастием, ПО ЗНАЧЕНИЮ переходит в прилагательное, существительное, местоимение: блестящие (отличные) способности, отдыхающие (в санатории), определенный (некоторый) успех.

Comment: К числу неморфологических способов образования относятся также лексико-синтаксический  и лексико-семантический способ. Лексико-синтаксический способ (сращение словосочетания в одно слово) - это способ словообразования, при котором происходит соединение двух или более слов в одно без каких-либо изменений в их морфемном составе и без участия соединительных гласных: сегодня (из "сего дня"), быстрорастворимый (из "быстро растворимый"), вышеизложенный (из "выше изложенный").

Comment: Лексико-семантический способ (употребление слова в новом значении) - это возникновение нового слова в результате семантического переосмысления старого слова на два слова-омонима: спутник (попутчик) — спутник (летательный аппарат), успевать (хорошо учиться).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В1-(20)... человек открывает новое... Открывает что?-новое- неморфологический способ- субстантивация-прилагательное перешло в существительное.

В3- когда постиг

в4-1, 2,8,9.Стремление  заложено ;потребность сильнее ;потери вечные, приносящие муки и страдания;оно несовместимо .

В5-(14)Изгнанный из рая человек сохранил...

В6-21,25

В7.-23.(синонимы мир-Вселенная)

Comment: Позволю себе подвергнуть сомнению некоторые Ваши .

В3. Мне почему-то казалось, что в данном случае "когда" - союз.

В4. В соответствии с моими скромными знаниями, когда в предложении есть указательное местоимение "это" в именительном падеже, как в предложении № 8, оно играет роль подлежащего; существительное "потери" будет сказуемым. Можно в состав сказуемого включить, я думаю, еще прилагательное "вечные", но причастный оборот, насколько мне известно, не может выполнять функцию сказуемого, разве нет?

Comment: В5. А не является ли сочетание "из рая" обстоятельством, ведь все-таки оно не входит в состав обособленного определения?

Comment: Насчёт В3 Вы правы, это союз. Задание некорректное. Но некоторые учёные говорят о наречных союзах = союзному слову в предложениях, где по смыслу просится в главной части ТОГДА.Я сочла за этот случай, но в школьной грамматике это недопустимо,"косяк"разработчиков.
В4.- я пропустила подлежащее, написала только сказуемое.Критерий Вы определили правильно: главное не то, что это потери, а то, что они вечные, приносящие муки и страдания.Причастный оборот может входить в сказуемое:"его знали как приносящего страдания"

Comment: В5-сочетание "из рая" -  обстоятельство,но   оно  входит в состав обособленного определения: изгнанный откуда?-из рая - зависимое слово.Причастный оборот как обос. определение можно разобрать ещё и по членам предложения.

Comment: В5. Но ведь в том-то и причина моих сомнений, что определение необособленное.

Comment: В чём сомнение? Что "Изгнанный из рая"-это причастный оборот, т.е. необособленное определение?Прич. оборот=распространённое определение=причастие с зависимыми словами. Трёхчленное словосочетание. Какие сомнения?. Этот же оборот после определяемого слова будет обособляться: Человек, изгнанный из рая, сохранил... Никаких сомнений - оборот.

Comment: > Какие сомнения?

Уже никаких, спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 1):

У меня складывается впечатление, что задание является неоправданно сложным, если учесть, что учащиеся должны его выполнить за ограниченное время и в нервной обстановке экзамена. Зачем включать туда  вопросы  повышенной трудности или неоднозначные вопросы, над которыми приходится спорить даже экспертам. Или, может быть, они попросту не видят этой сложности и неоднозначности?

Попробую привести несколько замечаний по теме.

1. Задание В3. Из предложения 22 выпишите словосочетание со связью примыкание. 
   (22) Когда человек, наблюдая за звёздами, постиг огромность мира, он испытал сознание своего ничтожества.  Можно ли сказать, что таким словосочетанием является  «когда постиг»?  Попробуем ответить на этот вопрос.

СПП можно разделить на два вида по типу связи: союзная связь и местоименная связь (ТО…ЧТО, ТАКОЙ…КАКОЙ, ТАК…КАК), причем указательные слова не всегда присутствуют в предложении, но почти всегда подразумеваются  (в школьной практике эта тема, скорее всего, не проходится).  СПП с придаточными времени стоят как бы на грани такого деления: есть указательное слово ТОГДА – это местоименная связь, нет указательного слова – это союзная связь. Предложение 22  имеет союзную связь, КОГДА относится ко всему предложению,   примыкания нет. Но перестроим предложение: «Он испытал сознание своего ничтожества ТОГДА, КОГДА постиг огромность мира». Здесь КОГДА – это союзное слово, связь примыкание.
И вывод: изучают ли в школе все эти тонкости, чтобы быстро и без труда разобраться во всем этом  на экзамене?

1. Задание В4. Среди предложений 1 — 10 найдите предложения с составными именными сказуемыми. Споры вызвало предложение (8) «Приобретая понимание природы, власть над ней, люди чего-то лишаются, не временно, а на всегда, ЭТО ПОТЕРИ вечные, приносящие муки и страдания». Попробуем решить вопрос  о составе сказуемого.

«Это потери» – предикативная основа предложения, «вечные, приносящие муки и страдания» – однородный ряд определений, отнесенный к сказуемому. Только позиция у ряда особая – после определяемого существительного, она позволяет переместить интонационное ударение  на оборот и выделить его. Попробуем изменить предложение: Это вечные, приносящие муки и страдания потери. Это всё тот же ряд, но в препозиции, теперь ударение падает на существительное, мысль не так выразительна, как в первом случае.
Примечание. Запятая после слова «лишаются» вызывает сомнение.

1. Задание В5. Среди предложений 1 — 15 найдите предложение с необособленным распространённым определением. Это предложение (14) «Изгнанный из рая человек сохранил в себе вкус познания…». В роли распространенного необособленного определения выступает причастный оборот. Причастный оборот – это причастие с зависимыми словами, он способен функционировать как  САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНАЯ ЕДИНИЦА, например: Человек, изгнанный из рая,  сохранил в себе вкус познания. Изгнанный из рая, человек сохранил в себе вкус познания – здесь обособление с целью придания обороту дополнительного обстоятельственного значения (хотя был изгнан, но сохранил).

Comment: Склонна считать,что В3-задание не неоправданно сложное, а некорректное для ЕГЭ, очередная ошибка разработчиков, в методичках их полно. Они деньги делают, не удосужась выверить задания. И в ответах много ошибок. А в В4 -разницы нет, что бы они за ответ ни взяли, всё будет верно, лишь бы нашли. В В5 сложности не вижу.

Comment: Задание не официальных разработчиков КИМов.  НА такие ориентироваться нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Прочитал я все ответы и комментарии, и меня посетила дерзкая мысль по поводу В-3. А может, искомое словосочетание со связью "примыкание" - это "постиг, наблюдая"? В своей практике я с такими случаями не сталкивался, но и с "когда постиг" согласиться не могу, ведь здесь явный союз "когда", который, кстати, можно заменить союзом "если"

Comment: А кстати, неплохая идея. Оборот обособляется, но ведь грамматическую связь никто не отменял. Например, "человек, изгнанный из рая" - здесь же связь согласования сохраняется. Это только вводные конструкции ни с чем не связаны.

Comment: Тест не похож на официальный тест ФИПИ. Дело в том, что в задании написано "выписать словосочетание", а в учебниках есть оговорка, что сочетания с обособленными членами не являются словосочетаниями. В тестах, созданных ФИПИ, подобных случаев не встречается. А вот в пробных тестах, созданных сторонними организациями и авторами - бывает. Я бы автору вопроса посоветовала зайти на сайт ФИПИ, там не только задания прошлых лет есть, они в этом году выкладывают задания предстоящего экзамена. Постепенно, к концу марта все будут. Уж представление об уровне сложности получит верное.

Comment: А по сути Вы можете ответить? Связаны слова "постиг, наблюдая" грамматической связью "примыкание" или нет?

Comment: Она и ответила по сути:примыкание-связь в словосочетании, а сочетания с обособленными членами словосочетаниями не являются. "Человек, изгнанный из рая" - тоже не словосочетание, там  согласуются определение и определяемое слово, но происходит это не в словосочетании.

Comment: Обособленные члены не образуют словосочетаний с определяемыми словами, но  грамматическая связь между ними, тем не менее, существует. А как тогда правильно охарактеризовать такую связь, есть какая-нибудь официальная терминология по этой теме?

Comment: Конечно существует, как и грамматическая связь между предикативными единицами(тоже не словосочетание, а связь там не согласование, а координация),связь отдельных синтаксических единиц в предложении всегда есть - это связь между членами предложения,она бывает присловная и припредикативная (неприсловная). Вот детерминант тоже не входит в словосочетание, а фразеологизм входит в слитное, несвободное словосочетание. Теория словосочетания сейчас довольно трудна.

Comment: "...там согласуются определение и определяемое слово, но происходит это не в словосочетании".Мне бы хотелось конкретно определить вид связи между обособленным причастием и существительным. Вроде бы там происходит ослабление синтаксической связи, установление полупредикативных отношений, но формально это то же согласование в роде, числе, падеже. Получается, что и есть связь, и нет связи. В учебниках (любых) как-то много не распространяются на эту тему. И как на уровне школьной программы (в общих чертах) можно охарактеризовать это явление?

Answer (score 0):

B1. Радиоволна. Слово образовано путем сращения словосочетания в одно слово.

В3. Не вижу словосочетаний с указанным видом связи.

В4. 1) Стремление к познанию ***заложено*** в натуре человека. (2) Эта потребность ***сильнее*** любых страхов.(З)Прометей похитил огонь, принёс его людям, боги жестоко и навечно наказали его за это. (4)Адам и Ева вкусили яблоко с древа познания, и уже новый библейский бог так же жестоко и навечно приговорил их к мукам. (5)Легенда повторилась. (б)Познание наказывается и требует жертв. (7)Знание надо оплачивать. (8) Приобретая понимание природы, власть над ней, люди чего-то лишаются, не временно, а навсегда, это ***потери*** вечные, приносящие муки и страдания. (9)Познание таит в себе горечь, отраву, оно ***несовместимо*** с раем. (Ю)Знания меняют структуру человеческой души, но человек не в силах отказаться от этих мук.

В5. (4)Адам и Ева вкусили яблоко ***с древа познания***, и уже новый библейский бог так же жестоко и навечно приговорил их к мукам.

В6. (21)Он творец, он создатель, он бог, человечество было сформировано не императорами, жрецами, полководцами, а теми, ***кто*** создал топор, колесо, самолёт, ***кто*** нашел злаки, следил за звёздами, ***кто*** открыл железо, полупроводники, радиоволны.(25)Считается, что наука не может не заботиться о пользе, и это правильно, но есть учёные, ***которые*** изучают природу не потому, что это полезно, «а потому, что природа прекрасна», как писал Анри Пуанкаре.

В7.(23) Безмерность Вселенной обескуражила его краткостью собственной жизни.